# Database values do not match data stream

Tags: php, mysql, sql, csv

For some odd reason, some database values do not match the datastream. It is not for every entry although. For instance a line from my CSV file is below.

```
00-1751,P,1649.95,1649.95,1237.00
```

And somehow in my DB the same entry reads

```
00-1751,P,999.99,999.99,999.99
```

My code for dumping into the DB is below:

```
function dump($csvFile, $conn){
if(($handle = fopen($csvFile, 'r')) !== false) {

    $header = fgetcsv($handle);
    $id = 0;

    $sql = "TRUNCATE TABLE inv_price";
    $sth = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $sth->execute();


    while(($data = fgetcsv($handle)) !== false) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO `inv_price` (sku, part_status, msrp, curr_sugg_retail, your_price) 
                VALUES ('$id', '$data[0]', '$data[1]', '$data[2]', '$data[3]')";
        print_r($data);
    try{
        $conn->query($sql);

    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
        die();
    }

        $id++;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
}
```

The `$data` printed to the console matches the CSV file. I am not sure how or why certain rows are changing the value to `999.99`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely explanation for this behavior is that the column is defined as datatype **`DECIMAL(5,2)`**, which allows for only three digits before the decimal point. And the error/warning is being ignored.

The value being stored in the column the maximum value that can be stored in that datatype.  We observe similar behavior with integer values as well.

[**SQL Fiddle Here** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a7577f/1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a7577f/1)

```
create table foo (col52 DECIMAL(5,2), col72 decimal(7,2));
insert ignore into foo (col52, col72) values (1234.56, 1234.56);

select * from foo;

col52   col72
------  -------
999.99  1234.56
```

---

On an entirely different note, the code appears to be vulnerable to SQL injection.

Curiously, the `TRUNCATE TABLE` statement is a prepared statement, but the `INSERT` is not.

```
  $sql = 'INSERT INTO `inv_price` (sku, part_status, msrp, curr_sugg_retail, your_price) 
          VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';

  $sth=conn->prepare($sql);
  $sth->bindParam(1,$id);
  $sth->bindParam(2,$data[0]);
  $sth->bindParam(3,$data[1]);
  $sth->bindParam(4,$data[2]);
  $sth->bindParam(5,$data[3]);
  $sth->execute();
```

Comment: Yeah, most bizarre situation the OP has. I kind of had a feeling it had something to do with what you pointed out.

Comment: Ah, loving it when one sees a green ticky, marking it as solved. Way to go ;-)

Comment: As far as the prepared statement - could i just prepare the same way i did the truncate or would i have to use the method you display above?

Comment: @AWood: There's no requirement that a prepared statement has to use bind placeholders and `bindParam`. But to do the insert using a prepared statement, but *not* using bind placeholders would be bizarre. That would disregard the *raison d'etre* of prepared statements.